# No index available on keyspace in couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I have a couchbase DB with documents stored, like

```
{
  "_host": {
    "kind": "KIND1",
    "id": "ID1",
..
}
```

I have created this index:

```
CREATE INDEX `kind-id-index` ON `dev`(`_host.kind`,`_host.id`)
```

but when I use this query

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where _host.kind=$1 and _host.id=$2 ")
```

I got this error:

```
No index available on keyspace dev_wk_state that matches your query.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back ticks are at wrong place. The index must be as follows.

```
CREATE INDEX `kind-id-index` ON `dev`(`_host`.`kind`,`_host`.`id`);
```

As there is no special characters in the fields you can omit back ticks also.

```
CREATE INDEX `kind-id-index` ON `dev`(_host.kind,_host.id);
```

FYI:
    _host is object and kind is field(nested) in object. You reference as _host.kind or `_host`.`kind`. If you do `_host.kind` it looking field "_host.kind" not sub object.
    If you want reference s1 you must use `f1.f2`.s1 because there is dot in the field you must do `f1.f2`.s1

```
{
  "_host": {
    "kind": "KIND1",
    "id": "ID1"
     },
  "f1.f2": { "s1": 10}
}
```